# Position an image to the left of a table row (outside of the table)

Tags: html, css

I've got a table, and some of the rows are hidden (display: none;).

I'd like to position an image just to the left of where the hidden row should be (to indicate that there is a hidden row here). It needs to be outside of the table, kind of floating just to the left of the row.

What's the best way to do this? Guessing it's some combination of float CSS property, relative or absolute positioning but haven't managed to hot a combination that works (the image either ends up inside the table, or worse, relative to the table itself, instead of relative to the table row.

Thanks

Comment: Re the downvote, not sure how much extra info to include in the question (I have tried lots of combinations of relative/absolute positioning and can list them all if that helps). Or if my question is not clear, please advise in what way, and I will try to clarify it.

Comment: You should begin to posting your HTML and CSS.

Comment: It's a general question about positioning something relative to a table's row really, but I'll knock up an example. One moment.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough without an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hiding the row you can hide the row elements. This allows us to conveniently use the `:before` pseudo selector.

[See a Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v23vS/).

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Fellow</td>       
  <td>Something</td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden">
  <td>Some</td>
  <td>Guy</td>      
  <td>Other</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Pal</td>
  <td>Dude</td>     
  <td>Misc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fellow</td>
  <td>Friend</td>       
  <td>Various</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    position: relative;
}

.hidden {
    display: inline; /* Fix height issue if it exists */
}

.hidden > td {
    display: none;
}

.hidden:before {
    content: ">"; /* You can insert an image here using url() */
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this looks exactly like what I am trying to achieve, and I've never come across the 'before' selector before. Will try it out and post back in a moment, thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, this works really well. Thanks Nit.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a hidden column to the left of that row and put this image inside a cell in this column, therefore appearing to be to the left of your existing table.

Please post some HTML to help understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks OllyRatio. Gone with Nit's answer but this is good too (my real table is massive so trying to avoid adding extra columns but I can see this would also work in plenty of scenarios)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`

`visibility: hidden` will hide your element but will mantain the element's height/width.

`display: none` will hide your element and its respective space, making hard to tell what row is hidden.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FLcYS/

Comment: Thanks Matheus. If I run into problems with Nit's approach I'll give this a try (and post back)